# How to update database with entity framework from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relational-database

I am a bit confused at how entity framework and MVC determine what HTML elements to use to update values in the db. I can get the data from the database to the model to display, but how do I create a custom interface in HTML/JS and get the values for the database to update with from DOM or JS objects? I have related data in the model (in a list) that I want to be able to update, but Im not sure how to hook everything up to make it work.

Comment: by custom interface you mean a form, say a client detail to be filled? just use ajax for it.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC, there's a concept of "modelbinding". Essentially, you create a set of fields with names that mirror the object or object hierarchy you want to bind that posted data to, based on convention. For example, if you have an action like:

```
public ActionResult Create(Foo foo)
```

And `Foo` has a property, `Bar`, then you'd have an input in your form with the name "Bar". When this gets posted to the action, the modelbinder will match up the name in the post data with the appropriate named property and set its value to that posted value. If your type is composed of another type, then you would use a `.` to chain the properties. For example, if `Bar` was itself a class with a property `Baz`, the the name of the input would be "Bar.Baz". For list types, you'd add an indexer, i.e. "Bars[0].Baz".

The `HtmlHelper` extensions provided by MVC take care of this naming logic for you, though, so it's usually better and easier to create your form inputs via something like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Bar)
```

Rather than manually trying to create an HTML input with the right name.

Importantly for list types, the modelbinder can only bind values to something that can be indexe, i.e. `List<T>` or `T[]`. Something like an `ICollection<T>` won't work, because it cannot be indexed. Usually, you'll need to use a view model when working with collections, so you can map to/from a list type that the modelbinder can work with and the `ICollection<T>` type Entity Framework requires for collections. That said, view models are good practice, regardless, as it negates a whole host of potential issues, simply by requiring you to think about how your data goes into the database.